# Parsing dSYM (Mach-O) File. Issue with Endianness

Tags: ios, arm, mach-o, dsym

I'm trying to write a simple parser for the mach-o file that is included inside the dSYM file. When I open the file on a hex editor (Hex Fiend or Hex dump on TextWrangler). I see something like this.

```
CEFAEDFE 0C000000 0B000000 0A000000 07000000 3C0D0000 
00000000 1B000000 18000000 A04EF320 E8603B93 AB88123C 
06AC3E9B ...
```

The first value `CEFAEDFE` is just `FEEDFACE` backwards which is the `MH_MAGIC` number. Actually, it is `MH_CIGMA` since it is backwards. This makes me thing that the rest of the info is little endian: the least significant byte first. In the case of `0xFEEDFACE`, the least significant byte is `0xCE`, which is first in my sample above, then the rest of the bytes.

So I carry on inspecting the rest of the integers (4 bytes). After rearranging them so they are properly formatted (i.e. 0C000000 becomes 0000000C), we have:

> 0000000C is the CPU type which is CPU_TYPE_ARM
>
> 0000000B is the CPU subtype which is CPU_SUBTYPE_ARM_V7S
>
> 0000000A is the filetype wich is MH_DSYM
>
> 00000007 is the number of load commands
>
> 00000D3C is the number of bytes occupied by the load commands
>
> 00000000 are the flags (no flags)
>
> 0000001B is the load command LC_UUID indicating that this LC contains the UUID
>
> 00000018 size of the load command which is 0x18 = 24 bytes (command [4 bytes] + size [4 bytes] + UUID [16 bytes])

**Now this is where it gets weird and where my questions come.**

Since the info is little endian, I thought the UUID (the following 16 bytes) should be rearranged "backwards" like this: 9B3EAC06-3C1288AB-933B60E8-20F34EA0. However, when I use `dwarfdump` to get the UUID (`dwarfdump --uuid TestApp.app.dSYM/`) I get this:

```
UUID: A04EF320-E860-3B93-AB88-123C06AC3E9B (armv7s) TestApp.app.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/TestApp
```

Why is this in big endian order? Why is it printed by `dwarfdump` in the same order that I see the bytes in Hex Fiend?

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance for your help or suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UUIDs are defined by [rfc4122](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) to be in "network byte order", also known as big-endian.

So, yes you need to read/write them that way even in otherwise little-endian structures.